# How to Join two different queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure and a get date range query.I want to join both the queries that it show one resultset only.
Procedure and query are given below..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ak_ReportData_CMTDB

  @BankAccountID uniqueidentifier,  
  @StartDate     datetime,  
  @EndDate       datetime  

AS  

----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
-- Name:     ak_ReportData_CMTDB  
-- Purpose:  Returns the daily activity on the passed bank account for the   
--           passed date range  
-- Input:    BankAccountID - The bank account to report on  
--           StartDate, EndDate - The date range to report on  
-- Output:   Recordset containing activity  
-- Return:   0 = Sucess  
--           >0 = Error  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

SET NOCOUNT ON  

DECLARE @OpeningBalance money  

-- Calculate opening balance for deposits  
SELECT NULL AS fDepositDate,  
       SUM(CASE fType  
            WHEN 0 THEN fAmount                    -- Deposit (Add amount)  
            WHEN 1 THEN (CASE fSide   
                          WHEN 1 THEN fAmount * -1 -- Transfer Out (Subtract amount)  
                          WHEN 2 THEN fAmount      -- Transfer In (Add amount)  
                                 ELSE 0   
                         END)  
            WHEN 2 THEN fAmount                    -- Credit Card (Add amount)  
            WHEN 3 THEN fAmount * -1               -- Withdrawal (Subtract amount)  
                   ELSE 0  
           END) As fNetChange  
FROM tBADepositMaster   
WHERE fBankAccountID = @BankAccountID  
  AND fDepositDate < @StartDate   
  AND fVoid = 0  

UNION ALL  

-- Calculate NetChange for deposits for each date  
SELECT fDepositDate,  
       SUM(CASE fType  
            WHEN 0 THEN fAmount                    -- Deposit (Add amount)  
            WHEN 1 THEN (CASE fSide   
                          WHEN 1 THEN fAmount * -1 -- Transfer Out (Subtract amount)  
                          WHEN 2 THEN fAmount      -- Transfer In (Add amount)  
                                 ELSE 0   
                         END)  
            WHEN 2 THEN fAmount                    -- Credit Card (Add amount)  
            WHEN 3 THEN fAmount * -1               -- Withdrawal (Subtract amount)  
                   ELSE 0  
           END) AS fNetChange  
FROM tBADepositMaster   
WHERE fBankAccountID = @BankAccountID  
  AND fDepositDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate  
  AND fVoid = 0  
GROUP BY fDepositDate 

UNION ALL

-- Calculate opening balance for checks  
SELECT NULL As fDepositDate,  
       SUM(fAmount) * -1 AS fNetChange  
FROM tBACheck  
WHERE fBankAccountID = @BankAccountID  
  AND fDate < @StartDate   
  AND fVoid = 0  

UNION ALL  

-- Calculate NetChange for checks for each date  
SELECT fDate As fDepositDate,  
       SUM(fAmount) * -1 AS fNetChange  
FROM tBACheck  
WHERE fBankAccountID = @BankAccountID  
  AND fDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate  
  AND fVoid = 0  
GROUP BY fDate  
ORDER BY fDepositDate
```

And get date range query

```
;WITH tmpinfo(tmpdt) AS 
(SELECT @StartDate 
UNION ALL 
SELECT tmpdt + 1 
FROM tmpinfo 
WHERE tmpdt < @EndDate ) 
SELECT * FROM tmpinfo OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Is it possible to join these two queries in single query?

Comment: I want to get all dates in between of StartDate and EndDate with Record of first Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

By one result set you mean you want to add second query result as an additional column into the first query. If yes, then you can use join to combine both queries with the common columns.